# Изменение цвета li в конкретном ul

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

есть задача на смену цвета li в ul, но только в конкретном ul, при нажатии на li в другом ul, старый li не затерался. Как это реализовать без id или с id, так как UL выводятся через цикл и их может быть не ограниченное множество.

```
  -----------<HTML>-------------- 

<ul class="list">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
</ul>

-----------<HTML>-------------- 

-----------<style>--------------

li{cursor: pointer;}
li.active{color: red;}

-----------<style>--------------

-----------<JS, Jquery>-------------- 

$('.list').on('click', 'li', function(){
$('.list li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});

-----------<JS, Jquery>--------------
```

Comment: Что означает 'старый li не затерался'?

Comment: что бы оставался с добавленным классом active{color: red;}

Comment: а старый это какой? То есть всегда при клике было всё выделенным? тогда надо  удалить строку `$('.list li').removeClass('active');`

Comment: Нет, доаустим я нажал на <li>2</li> и он поменял цвет, а затем я нажал на <li>6</li> он поменял цвет и что бы <li>2</li> оставался то же в красном цвете

Comment: ой, то есть `$('.list li').removeClass('active');` надо удалить

Comment: Этот код рабочий, но только когда существует 1 ul, когда их несколько то при нажатии класс active удаляется со всех li всех ul, надо что бы он работал только в ul на которые li нажаты

Answer (score 0):

Такое?

```js
$('.list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).closest('.list').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

---

или такое?

```js
$('.list').on('click', 'li', function() {
   // $(this).closest('.list').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да!!! СПАСИБО это оно!

Comment: @DimaBuljgo Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть на галочку рядом с ответом)